# Form issue on my website

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a form and when I save it the chosen value in the forum doesn't appear on the good page.

The goal of this form is to create a specific task for an employee, when the form is validated, the task appear on the employee tasks page.

I modified a part of the form, the "Priority" part, I added a dropdown menu instead of a text area.

Here are the codes:

- Form PART.

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="taskPriority"><?php echo $priorityField; ?> <sup><?php echo $reqField; ?></sup></label>
         <select name="taskPriority" class="form-control" name="taskPriority" required="" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['taskPriority']) ? $_POST['taskPriority'] : ''; ?>" />
            <option value="urgent">URGENT</option>
            <option value="important">IMPORTANT</option>
            <option value="normal">NORMAL</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="taskDue"><?php echo $taskDueField; ?> <sup><?php echo $reqField; ?></sup></label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taskDue" id="taskDue" required="" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['taskDue']) ? $_POST['taskDue'] : ''; ?>" />
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="addCal" value="1">
         <?php echo $addToCalField; ?>
         </label>
      </div>
      <span class="help-block"><?php echo $addToCalFieldHelp; ?></span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="taskStatus"><?php echo $statusField; ?> <sup><?php echo $reqField; ?></sup></label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taskStatus" required="" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['taskStatus']) ? $_POST['taskStatus'] : ''; ?>" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="taskDesc"><?php echo $taskDescField; ?> <sup><?php echo $reqField; ?></sup></label>
         <textarea class="form-control" required="" name="taskDesc" rows="5"><?php echo isset($_POST['taskDesc']) ? $_POST['taskDesc'] : ''; ?></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

- Salary Task Page PART:

```html
<tr>
   <td data-th="<?php echo $taskTitleField; ?>">
      <a href="index.php?page=viewTask&taskId=<?php echo $row['empTaskId']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $viewTaskTooltip; ?>">
      <?php echo clean($row['taskTitle']); ?>
      </a>
   </td>
   <td data-th="<?php echo $createdByField; ?>"><?php echo clean($row['postedBy']); ?></td>
   <td data-th="<?php echo $priorityField; ?>"><?php echo clean($row['taskPriority']); ?></td>
   <td data-th="<?php echo $statusField; ?>"><?php echo clean($row['taskStatus']); ?></td>
   <td data-th="<?php echo $dateCreatedField; ?>"><?php echo $row['startDate']; ?></td>
   <td data-th="<?php echo $dateDueField; ?>"><?php echo $row['dueDate']; ?></td>
   <td data-th="<?php echo $actionText; ?>">
      <a href="index.php?page=viewTask&taskId=<?php echo $row['empTaskId']; ?>">
      <i class="fa fa-edit text-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="<?php echo $viewTaskTooltip; ?>"></i>
      </a>
      <a data-toggle="modal" href="#completeTask<?php echo $row['empTaskId']; ?>">
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o text-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="<?php echo $markTaskCmpTooltip; ?>"></i>
      </a>
      <a data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteTask<?php echo $row['empTaskId']; ?>">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="<?php echo $deleteTaskTooltip; ?>"></i>
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that the chosen priority (Urgent, Important or Normal) doesn't appear, like on the photo.

[image: demonstration]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Any particular reason why you chose `div` tags instead of `form`? Might be easier to read if you wrote it with `form` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is more code involved. Inside the "Task Page" you refer to `$row`. Where is it defined. I think it's a DB result, perhaps you need to add the new property `taskPriority` there also.
Same for you DB structure.

It would be helpful if you can provide more information.